# How to list only XML nodes located directly under the root node

Tags: c#, xml, listview, nodes, xmldocument

For example, how can I list `player1`, `player2`, and `player3` in a .NET 4.0 `ListView`?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<players>
  <player1>
    <name>playername</name>
    <age>18</age>
    <gender>m</gender>
  </player1>
  <player2>
    <name>playername</name>
    <age>18</age>
    <gender>m</gender>
  </player2>
  <player3>
    <name>playername</name>
    <age>18</age>
    <gender>m</gender>
  </player3>
</players>
```

Comment: Use XPath. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Linq to XML (which I suggest you to use with .Net 4.0) you can get them:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var players = xdoc.Root.Elements();
```

Or getting name attributes:

```
var names = from p in xdoc.Root.Elements()
            select (string)p.Element("name");
```

There is no benefit of XmlDocument usage, because it also loads all xml into memory. If you want to get only xml element names:

```
var players = from p in xdoc.Root.Elements()
              select p.Name.LocalName; // player1, player2, player3
```